# Flow control in pipeline based of frame rate in appsrc

Tags: gstreamer

**Flow control in pipeline based of frame rate in appsrc**

I would like to set framerate for below pipeline, Which takes data from appsrc.

Th Flow is:

```
 appsrc->encoder->mux->udpsink
```

In appsrc, i have push buffer callback which continuously push data into pipeline.
But now, i would like to control the flow based on frame rate.
How would i set timestamp to GstBuffer, so that flow control will be there?
Or is there any other way to Control flow in appsrc?

Comment: you can set PTS and Duration on gstbuffer if I understand you correctly, like this: `GST_BUFFER_PTS(buf)=some_pts` the same with `GST_BUFFER_DURATION` - here you set duration between frames according to your FPS, all this before push to appsrc

Comment: yeah, in the same way i had solved it. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `duration = gst_util_uint64_scale_int (1, GST_SECOND, fps);` is more elegant way

Answer (score 1):

**I Solved it.**

By using the Following code.

```
                buffer->pts = mPts;
                bufferuf->duration = (1.0/framerate)*(1000000000);

                mPts = mPts + buffer->duration;
```